# Create a Math Document help!

Tags: installing

I am an undergrad and am currently doing my first research project.  I would like to start typing my work as I have to begin writing a paper soon and also I wnat to start doing my proof homework in typed format.  I dowloaded TexWorks as it seemed like a good program for typing in LaTex.  I am new to this so I do not know where to start.  I have the basic formats to begin creating articles and stuff but TexWorks says I need a typesetting program.  First of all, is there a program out there that already has one installed?  Or is there a good one to get that works with TexWorks.  Also, if anyone has any suggestions of something better to use, I am open for that.  I just need to get to the point where I have the code on the left and the output on the right of a window and I can figure out the syntax and coding from there.  Please some advice to get going!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used MiKTex 2.9 and TexMaker for years and I think it works very well. Therefore, I suggest that you can use it.

For MiKTex, The website to download: http://miktex.org/2.9/setup ;

For TexMaker, http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmakerwin32_install.exe (for Windows system). There is also a version for Apple: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14641/texmaker][3](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14641/texmaker).

The most convenient is that the program will show several related arguments when you type first several letters of that argument. For example, if I type \al, and the program will show "\alpha " automatically. I think it is very easy to learn LaTex argument in this way.

Enjoy!

Comment: You should note that MikTeX is only available on Windows, so if the OP is on Linux or Mac, that advice is not very helpful.

Comment: Oh, really? I usually use Windows so that I am not so familiar with Mac. Thank you for inform me!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall TeXWorks for now.  (The next thing you install will reinstall it for you, or something similar.)  Now, if you use Windows, install MikTeX.  If Mac, install MacTeX.  Otherwise TeX Live.

If you have a local TeX wizard (wizard is a relative term: any one who knows more than you is somewhat wizardly), you may want to ask them what they have installed, so that you can install the same thing.  For instance, if they have TeX Live, you should ignore my advice and just install TeX Live, so that when you run into trouble you have someone nearby who can help.  (Such advice should be taken in moderation.  When I was starting out, my local wizard used Emacs.  Nevertheless, I use TexWorks, since I wasn't about to learn Emacs and TeX at the same time: that way lies madness :)  Likewise, you don't want to switch your OS just to take advantage of local wizards.)

Comment: TeXWorks will be included in any of these installations, as will various typesetting engines, and TeXWorks will know where to find the typesetting engines that are installed.